# Oracle Apex auto populate form based on existing data for each group

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a form where data is rendered from table assignments.

Currently in prerendering:

```
Begin
select group,status,task into :P1_GROUP,:P1_STATUS,:P1_TASK from assignments where id = :ID;
end;
```

Now in prerendering i need to write code such that if there is even just 1 entry for any group, the task column autopopulates for any other status.

[image]

i.e. For group A once user has filled info for any status say Alpha, the next time for any other status chosen, the task column should be updated same as that for Alpha.

So for any other the user fills form, the task column should auto populate while rendering.

Expected result:

[image]
How can this be handled?

Ape : 20.2

Answer (score 0):

Try with a subquery which - for the `:ID` value - returns the "maximum" (which is also the only) value stored in the `task` column. Something like this:

```
select group, 
  status, 
  -- 
  (select max(b.task) 
   from assignments b
   where b.id = :ID
  ) as task
into :P1_GROUP, :P1_STATUS, :P1_TASK 
from assignments a where a.id = :ID;
```

Comment: In case of interactive grid, how can this be achieved? I tried prepopulating by creating items but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870681/oracle-apex-prepopulate-ig-fields-based-on-condition