# Oracle Apex Prepopulate IG fields based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid in application where i need to prepopulate a columns value.
The current query is:

```
select id, project , phase , deadline from proj_depts;
```

Here the deadline needs to be prepopulated and if there is entry even for 1 phase, the same should prepopulate for all the phases for only one project 'abc'.

[image]

I need to write something like:

```
select id, project, phase, case when project = 'abc' max(deadline) else deadline end as deadline from proj_Depts;
```

To explain further, for only one particular project 'abc', the deadline should always come prepopulated as the max  value.

So in database, value should become:

[image]

So instead of user entering same deadline value for all phases of project 'abc', once there is entry for even one phase, the deadlines should be autopopulated.

Apex: 20.2

Comment: Can there be multiple non-null `deadline` values for a single `project`?  So phase 1 has a March deadline but phase 2 has a May deadline?  Is `deadline` actually a `date`?  Or is it a `varchar2`?  If projects have a single deadline, you really ought to have a `project` table with the deadline and a `project_phase` table that does not have a deadline.  Then the grid would simply join the two tables together.

Comment: Deadline is varchar,  there will be one value for deadline that user will input and after that  all other phases for that project deadline would prepopulate.

Comment: If user gives phase 1 as March, next time all other phases should show March for abc

Comment: Can this not be handled in grid query or via prerendering?

Comment: Can it?  Sure.  But if there is really supposed to be a single value for `deadline` per project, having the data model set up correctly will make things vastly easier.

Comment: Thats true, but as of now needs to be handled via query only which i am unable to achieve